# Cannot recognice object in video

Tags: python, opencv

I'm working on a school-project.

I've been given the task to identify objects when seeing them with a camera.

[Video](https://1drv.ms/v/s!ArwJu8K9-qppgcgtIQpGD0EXszFpPw)

[Image](https://1drv.ms/u/s!ArwJu8K9-qppgcguR1Vop0v9lUXCqA)

I've chosen to try `template matching`:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import cv2

template = cv2.imread('./frog.jpg') # read image as template
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('./frog.mov') # simulate camera input

height = template.shape[0]
width = template.shape[1]

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read() # read the current frame

    if ret is False:
        break
    res = cv2.matchTemplate(frame, template, cv2.TM_CCORR_NORMED)

    min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv2.minMaxLoc(res)

    top_left = max_loc
    bottom_right = (top_left[0] + width, top_left[1] + height)

    cv2.rectangle(frame,top_left, bottom_right, 255, 2)

    match_found = False

    for i in res:
        if i.any() > 0.9999:
            print ('match found')
            match_found = True
            break 

    if match_found:
        plt.subplot(121),plt.imshow(res,cmap = 'gray')
        plt.title('Matching Result'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
        plt.subplot(122),plt.imshow(frame,cmap = 'gray')
        plt.title('Detected Point'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
        plt.suptitle('TM_CCORR_NORMED')
        plt.show()
```

The problem is, that almost everything is matching.
How can I get this to work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would use [frog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQ66q.jpg) and [bear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9PDK0.jpg) images you will get 100% objects matching. Following script detects these images on video and shows names of detected objects:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import cv2

images = {'Frog': cv2.imread('frog.jpg'), 'Bear': cv2.imread('bear.jpg')}
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('frog.mov')  # simulate camera input

while cap.isOpened():
    ret, frame = cap.read()  # read the current frame
    if ret:
        for name, image in images.items():
            match = cv2.matchTemplate(frame, image, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
            _, quality, _, max_loc = cv2.minMaxLoc(match)
            if quality > 0.99:

                top_left = max_loc
                bottom_right = (top_left[0] + image.shape[1], top_left[1] + image.shape[0])
                cv2.rectangle(frame, top_left, bottom_right, 255, 2)
                plt.subplot(121), plt.imshow(match, cmap='gray')
                plt.title('Matching Result'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
                plt.subplot(122), plt.imshow(frame, cmap='gray')
                plt.title('Detected Point'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
                plt.suptitle(name)
                plt.show()
    else:
        break
```

So what I have on the end:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you know how I could tell which toy I have detected ? So I can print like: 'This is a frog', This is a 'Dinosaur' or sth ?